# Alternative to views in Xcode

Tags: xcode, view

I'm an Xcode noob; I have created a view-based Xcode project. In the first view, the user has to choose an option from a list (in the list there are more than 200 options). In the second view, he has to choose a sub-option, and even this list is really long. Each sub-option should have its own view, but since it's impossible to create more than 20,000 views in Xcode, I should use an alternative method. Can you help me please?

Comment: You might want to look into Core Data - http://goo.gl/9WMhoa

Comment: Why not create a single view controller that accepts a list of data?

Comment: @rmaddy Could you tell me how can do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So to check this over, you are looking for not one but two UITable view's both of which have lots of data.

First you need to decide and figure out, how will you store this data of information in the app: IE: core data,  plist, arrays, server end (json,xml) etc...    secondly, how much information will be displayed at once?  just a picture and maybe two liens of text ? or do you want something more custom ??

once you have decided that you can actually start to begin a basic project (Navigation Based Application)(would be easiest for a new user) or starting with Blank Project (Single Based View Controller) and  in IB (Interface Builder) addend a UITableView along with a UITableView Cell.

Here is some basic tutorials for designing UITableViews. :-)

Step 1 - Learn The Basics of UITable View - 
[Basic UITableView with NSArray TUTORIAL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUElbsmi67Y)

Step 2 - Learn how to make your own UITableViewCell - [Custom Cell Tutorial (Storyboard) - Xcode 4.6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvPhq5QZHys)

Any questions just ask, hope that helps :-)

A book might be a good place to start as well, I learned my many of my first UITableView off of a book. [Beginning iPhone Development: Exploring the iPhone SDK [Paperback]
Dave Mark](http://www.amazon.ca/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430216263)